# Removing a temporary file in Python

Tags: python, join, zip

This is my existing code to zip a folder which I have put together mostly from help on here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M")
target_dir = '/var/lib/data'
temp_dir='/tmp'

zip = zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(temp_dir, now+".zip"), 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
rootlen = len(target_dir) + 1
for base, dirs, files in os.walk(target_dir):
   for file in files:
      fn = os.path.join(base, file)
      zip.write(fn, fn[rootlen:])
```

If I wanted to remove the zip file I just created at the end of the opperation, would the best command be this?

```
os.remove.join(temp_dir, now+".zip")
```

Comment: Yes. Though you might as well also have saved the name of your file in an variable such as `filename` if you're going to use it more than once.

Comment: should that be os.remove(os.path.join(...))?

Comment: If I wanted to make filename into a variable I would do this? filename = 'os.path.join(temp_dir, now+".zip")'

Comment: ^ drop the single quotes, and then yes, that would be it.

Comment: Or, based on your recommendation...filename='os.remove(os.path.jointemp_dir, now+".zip"))'

Comment: filename=os.remove(os.path.jointemp_dir, now+".zip"))

Comment: i think he meant to use the ` type quotes that mark somethign as code ...

Comment: Ak. I dont get it. Change the "'s surrounding zip to single ' ?

Comment: `filename = os.path.join(temp_dir, now+".zip")`. And then you can use use `zipfile.ZipFile(filename, 'w', …)` and `os.remove(filename)`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `os.remove(os.path.join(temp_dir, now + ".zip"))` will be fine.

However, you should ensure that it is executed properly in every case you want it to.

If it is to be removed in any case, you could do

```
create it
try:
    work with it
finally:
    remove it
```

But in this case, you could as well use the `tempfile` module:

```
import tempfile
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.zip') as t:
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(t.name, 'w') # re-create it
    do stuff with z
# after the with clause, the file is gone.
```

If, however, you want it to be gone only under special circumstances (on  success, on error, ...) you are stuck with `os.remove(os.path.join(temp_dir, now+".zip"))` and you should use it whenever the file is to be deleted.

```
try:
    do_stuff
except VerySpecialException:
    os.remove(os.path.join(temp_dir, now+".zip")) # do that here for a special exception?
    raise # re-raise
except: # only use a bare except if you intend to re-raise
    os.remove(os.path.join(temp_dir, now+".zip")) # or here for all exceptions?
    raise # re-raise
else:
    os.remove(os.path.join(temp_dir, now+".zip")) # or here for success?
```

Comment: Interesting that there's even a module for temporary files. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 3):

This would be the way to do it:

```
os.remove(os.path.join(temp_dir, now+".zip"))
```

have fun,  Mike

Answer (score 2):

Consider using Python's [built in temporary file library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html).  It handles the cleanup of the tempfile when it is closed.